# How can I automatically tab to the next field using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

In jQuery, how can I trigger the behavior of a user tabbing to the next input field?

I've tried this:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 9; // # Key code for the Tab key
$("input").trigger(e);
```

But triggering the event doesn't move the cursor to the next field.

I suppose I could move the cursor manually using `focus()`, but deciding which field should be next is something the browser already knows how to do, so it seems much cleaner to just trigger a tab.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455225/how-do-i-move-focus-to-next-input-with-jquery). If for example you want to move focus to the next field when a certain number of characters have been entered, you could use that code in the `keyup` event, and check the entered number of characters.

The code in that answer works by getting the set of inputs in the form, finding the selected input and adding 1 to the index of the selected input, and then triggering the `focus` event on the element with that index.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one solution, via http://jqueryminute.com/set-focus-to-the-next-input-field-with-jquery/

```
$.fn.focusNextInputField = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var fields = $(this).parents('form:eq(0),body').find(':input').not('[type=hidden]');
        var index = fields.index( this );
        if ( index > -1 && ( index + 1 ) < fields.length ) {
            fields.eq( index + 1 ).focus();
        }
        return false;
    });
};
```

The use is as follows:

```
$( 'current_field_selector' ).focusNextInputField();
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a JQuery plugin available:

http://www.mathachew.com/sandbox/jquery-autotab/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

`$("input").trigger( 'keypress', e );`

as a solution?
I find sometimes being explicit is best.
If that doesn't work possibly even

`$("input").trigger( 'keypress', [{preventDefault:function(){},keyCode:9}] );`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Simulating key press wont work, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428993/why-doesnt-simulating-a-tab-keypress-move-focus-to-the-next-input-field