# How can I set the focus to the next field (based on tabindex) using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I automatically tab to the next field using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360594/how-can-i-automatically-tab-to-the-next-field-using-jquery)

Is it possible to simulate the pressing of the <kbd>tab</kbd> key with JavaScript?

I would like the focus to be switched to the field with the next highest [`tabindex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex), just as actually pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> would.

Comment: Can you be more specific about iterating, is that means looping through all elements which has a `tabindex` ?

Comment: @chc1201 I rephrased the question, if this is not what you meant please clarify.

Comment: @Adam, I think,you have just changed the whole meaning of the original question, may be not a good idea.

Comment: @SheikhHeera I don't think I did, the OP specifically mentioned that he was trying to "simulate a tab press". Continually pressing tab would iterate through all the fields on the page as the OP described.

Comment: Might not be an exact duplicate of the other questions. Since I don't see any that use tabindex.