# Why doesn't simulating a tab keypress move focus to the next input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Note [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214125/simulate-pressing-tab-key-with-jquery) question. I see that there are other approaches besides just triggering the tab keypress event, but I'd still like to know why triggering the tab key press event doesn't move focus to the next input field.

[Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYNLjE?editors=101)

**HTML**

```
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
```

**JS**

```
$('textarea').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.metaKey && e.which === 40) {
    console.log('test');
    $(this).trigger({
      type: 'keypress',
      which: 9
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because the tab event is a native browser event/action for changing focus. The `.trigger()` function only triggers the event handlers that are assigned to it. Note there is more information given from [jQuery's site](https://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/):

> **The .trigger() function cannot be used to mimic native browser events**, such as clicking on a file input box or an anchor tag. This is because, there is no event handler attached using jQuery's event system that corresponds to these events.

There is a plug-in for this though called [**jquery-simulate**](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-simulate/) to handle this. That being said the `tab` key changing focus is actually a default action in the web browser. Firing a browsers native event does not mean it will do it's default action, as the documentation for [**KeyboardEvents**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) mentions:

> Note that manually firing an event does not generate the default action associated with that event. For example, manually firing a key event does not cause that letter to appear in a focused text input. In the case of UI events, this is important for security reasons, as it prevents scripts from simulating user actions that interact with the browser itself.

Comment: So `.trigger()`ing the event isn't the same as... triggering the event manually? That's misleading. Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Any idea why [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYNLjE?editors=101) isn't working? The page you linked to [says](https://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/#how-can-i-mimic-a-native-browser-event-if-not-trigger) "...can programmatically create an event that behaves exactly as if someone has actually...". I did everything in [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) guide, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @AdamZerner That's actually a bit misleading, in the documentation for the [`KeyEvents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent). There is a note at the bottom of the page which mentions: *"Note that manually firing an event does not generate the default action associated with that event. For example, manually firing a key event does not cause that letter to appear in a focused text input. In the case of UI events, this is important for security reasons, as it prevents scripts from simulating user actions that interact with the browser itself."*