# Trying to dispatch keypress event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keyevent, react-ref

I have a component with an input element and I would like to trigger a "tab" keypress event on that input element in order to jump to the next input element whenever a certain set of logic happens.

I have a ref on the first input element and I'm attempting to trigger the keypress event like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (ref.current) {
    ref.current.focus();
    setTimeout(() => {
      ref.current.dispatchEvent(
        new KeyboardEvent("keypress", { key: "Tab" })
      );
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

First I make sure to select the first input element with `.focus()`, then after 3 seconds I trigger pressing the tab key, expecting to see the focus move to the next field, but it does not seem to work.

It may seem like a strange example, but this is just a prototype. What I am actually planning to do is to trigger some code when I submit the first input field, that will fetch some rows with additional input fields and once that has been rendered I need to trigger the "tab" key. I would like to avoid attaching refs to these dynamically loaded input fields as I feel it adds a lot of overhead keeping track of the refs and passing them down, when all I need is to leverage the tab order and simulate a keypress to tab to the first dynamic loaded item once it has loaded. I'm ok with adding a single ref to the field you need to submit to populate the dynamic fields.

I noticed a few examples online calling `.dispatchEvent()` directly on the ref object, but if I try that I get an error telling that the function does not exist, so I call it on the `current` prop instead. Not sure if that has any relevance.

Here is a link to a prototype where the above code was taken from: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-hopper-vrh4w?file=/src/App.js:149-441

Comment: It appears this is not possible to do via javascript DOM events per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428993/why-doesnt-simulating-a-tab-keypress-move-focus-to-the-next-input-field

Comment: Unfortunately you seem to be right. See the note about manually firing events not triggering native browser actions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Answer (score 5):

Per the answer I got in the comments it appears that you cannot trigger native browser behaviour (as a security feature) by emulating keystrokes (there's a note about 2/3 down the page): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { keyCode: "Tab", which: 9 })
```

Here's how I got the `which` https://keycode.info/

Comment: Your `keyCode` is incorrect, it should also be `9`. `key` and `code` should be `'Tab'`. If you use https://keyjs.dev/ instead, you can use a hidden feature to copy the whole `KeyboardEvent` object: Just open DevTools and in the console, you will see all the events being logged and you can expand the one you want to copy.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @funkylaundry, you can't trigger native browser actions by dispatching your own events for security reasons.

However, what you want to do can be achieved with the [`autofocus` (HTML)](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp) / `autoFocus` (JSX) attribute, as shown below:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [showExtraFields, setShowExtraFields] = React.useState(false);
  const [showMoreExtraFields, setShowMoreExtraFields] = React.useState(false);
  
  React.useEffect((e) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShowExtraFields(true);
    }, 3000);
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShowExtraFields(false);
      setShowMoreExtraFields(true);
    }, 6000);
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShowExtraFields(true);
      setShowMoreExtraFields(true);
    }, 9000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <form>
      <input placeholder="Input 1" autoFocus />
      
      { showExtraFields && (<React.Fragment>
        <input placeholder="Input 2" autoFocus />
        <input placeholder="Input 3" />
        <input placeholder="Input 4" />
      </React.Fragment>) }
      
      { showMoreExtraFields && (<React.Fragment>
        <input placeholder="Input 5" autoFocus />
        <input placeholder="Input 6" />
        <input placeholder="Input 7" />
      </React.Fragment>) }
    </form>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 8px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Note how the focus goes `Input 1 -> Input 2 -> Input 5 -> Input 2`.

Basically, if there's more than one input with `autoFocus` on the page, the last element to be mounted gets it. That's why in the last update, when both groups of inputs are shown, the focus goes to `Input 2`, which has just been mounted, rather than `Input 5`, which comes after `Input 2` but was already present on the page.