# click and keydown event firing page navigation angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension for someone disabled that can only click a mouse I was wondering if there is anyway to similate a page down event (I would love to just be able to send a keydown event to move page but I dont know if this is posible check out the links [Fire tab keypress event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601593/fire-tab-keypress-event-in-javascript) http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents  very upsetting I thought this would be easy).
Is there any work around the firing keyevent (because this would make my life a lot easier also for the other keys instead of just getting the element that has been onfocus).

Comment: Just use `window.scrollBy(0, innerHeight)` inside a content script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript

Comment: @wOxxOm is there anyway to simulate a tab press for navigation to select selectable elements

Comment: Welp... [Simulating the TAB keydown: focusing next element as determined by \`tabIndex\`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7303507)

Comment: @wOxxOm also I would like to get the keyboard to work for every separate and different types of text areas on page  would I have to do this manually if I could just simulate a keypress somehow

Comment: As explained in the answer you've linked, there is no universal magical method, you'll have to implement every function manually as shown in the "Simulating the TAB keydown" link above.

Comment: Normally, this job gets done easily with an external key-remapping utility like AutoHotkey etc.