# Move focus to next input in another div

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
 <div class="postcode">
    <div>
        <input type="text" maxlength="4">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" maxlength="4">
    </div>  
</div>
```

I need Jquery to automatically focus on the next input once 4 characters have been entered. I have tried the following, but this only works if the inputs are next to each other:

```
$(".postcode input").keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      $(this).next('.postcode input').focus();
    }
});
```

This also means that when I shift+tab, it keeps focusing on the next div.

Lastly, I also need it to go back to the first input if the user deletes all characters from the second input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I move focus to next input with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455225/how-do-i-move-focus-to-next-input-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Move to the next Input

Use `parent()` to select the parent `<div>`, move to the `next()` DIV, and `find()` the child input to focus on it. Note that you should add `:first` in order to apply the function on the first `input`.

```
$(".postcode input:first").keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      $(this).parent().next().find('input').focus();
    }
});
```

### Shift+Tab keeps on focus

Add `focus` event to trigger the same input's `keyup` event to focus the second input again.

```
$(".postcode input:first").keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      $(this).parent().next().find('input').focus();
    }
}).focus(function(){
    $(this).trigger('keyup');
});
```

Comment: That works exactly as it should, thanks! How do I do the opposite so that when the character count gets to 0 (or maybe when its zero and the user presses backspace) in the second box, the focus goes back on the first?

Answer (score 0):

try this code that id for each input and add all code in documuent read function :

```
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id1").keyup(function () {
  if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
  $('#id2').focus();
  }
  });
  });
  </script>
  <div class="postcode">
  <div>
    <input id="id1" type="text" maxlength="4">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="id2" type="text" maxlength="4">
  </div>  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I used (partly suggested by Alon Pini):

```
jQuery(function($) {

    // Tab to next item when maxlength is reached
    $(".postcode div:nth-child(1) input").keyup(function () {
        if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
            $(this).parent().next().find('input').focus();
        }
    });

    // Tab to previous item when pressing backspace and character count is 0
    $("postcode div:nth-child(2) input").on('keyup', function(e) {
        if(e.which==8) {
            if (this.value.length == 0) {
                $(this).parent().prev().find('input').focus();
            }
        }
    });

});
```

This solution does both, focuses on next item when character count has reached max length, and focuses on previous item when character count has reached zero in the second input field.