# Javascript: Remap Keyboard in Input

Tags: javascript, triggers, key, keydown, remap

I found some threads related to this topic but I can't seem to figure out my err.
I want to remap the arrowDown Button to the Tab-Button, when arrowDown is pressed in a input-field. *edit3: So that I can focus/change to the next input field. I'd like to navigate through those inputs via the arrowDown-btn.

Based on what I found, I got to this point:

```
    $("input").keyup(function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode;
        if (keyCode === 40) {
            var k = jQuery.Event("keydown");
            k.which = 50;
            $(this).trigger(k);
        } else {
            alert("Wrong Key.");
        }
    });
```

$(this).trigger(k) doesn't seem to work. I think I misunderstood the concept of triggering a specific button.

EDIT1 (based on suggestion in comments):

```
    $("input").bind("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 40) { //if this is enter key
        e.preventDefault();
        var newE = $.Event("keyup");
        newE.keyCode = 9;
        $(this).trigger(newE);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

is a slighty different approach but still, the tabulator is not pressed when I press arrowDown.

EDIT2:
It's not just the tabulator button, I can't trigger any key with this setup.

```js
    $("input").keyup(function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode;
        if (keyCode === 40) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var newE = $.Event("keydown");
            newE.keyCode = 60;
            $(this).trigger(newE);
        } else {
            alert("Oh no you didn't.");
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Remapping Keys</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Deutsch" class="card h-auto w-fitContent mt-3">
    <div class="card-header sub-header">
        <a><h4>Deutsch<br></h4></a></div>
    <div class="card-body pr-3"><table><tbody><tr>

        <td></td><input type="hidden" id="titel5" value="1.01 - Pausenspiele"><td class="pr-2 font-weight-light">
        <table>
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>1.01</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>Pausenspiele</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody></table>
    </td><td class="pl-1">
        <input type="text" class="" id="aufg5" name="DL3419" value="3" size="2" maxlength="2">
        <span class="ml-1"><code style="color:#12AC14; font-size:11pt; "> <b>  </b>  </code></span></td></tr>
    <tr>

        <td></td><input type="hidden" id="titel6" value="1.02 - Pausenspiele"><td class="pr-2 font-weight-light">
        <table>
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>1.02</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>Pausenspiele</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody></table>
    </td><td class="pl-1">
        <input type="text" class="" id="aufg6" name="DL3420" value="4" size="2" maxlength="2">
        <span class="ml-1"><code style="color:#12AC14; font-size:11pt; "> <b>  </b>  </code></span></td></tr>
    <tr>

        <td></td><input type="hidden" id="titel7" value="1.03 - Pausenspiele"><td class="pr-2 font-weight-light">
        <table>
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>1.03</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>Pausenspiele</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody></table>
    </td><td class="pl-1">
        <input type="text" class="" id="aufg7" name="DL3421" value="3" size="2" maxlength="2">
        <span class="ml-1"><code style="color:#12AC14; font-size:11pt; "> <b>  </b>  </code></span></td></tr>

    </tbody></table></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT4:
I made a demo-snippet w/ described problem.

EDIT5 (SOLVED):
I solved the issue using [How do I move focus to next input with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455225/how-do-i-move-focus-to-next-input-with-jquery)
Triggering the tabulator via keypress doesn't seem to work for whatever reasons. I'd appreciate further clarifications.
What did the trick for me was :

```
    $(function() {
    var focusables = $(":input:not([type=hidden])");
    focusables.keyup(function(e) {
        var maxchar = false;
        if (e.keyCode === 40) {
            var current = focusables.index(this),
                next = focusables.eq(current+1).length ? focusables.eq(current+1) : focusables.eq(0);
            console.log(next);
            next.focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger a keypress/keydown/keyup event in JS/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368578/trigger-a-keypress-keydown-keyup-event-in-js-jquery)

Comment: I already found this one, but I didnt get it to work.
I'll edit my second approach to the original post. The code recognizes the correct button when pressed but the tabulator is not triggered. 
I found out that the keycode for tabulator is 9, but it still does not trigger said tabulator.